# What determines the color of the request in the Network tab in Chrome Developer Console?

Tags: http, google-chrome-devtools

I have a response with status of 200 OK, but it is showing up as red in the list of network requests.  I thought it was the status that would determine this but clearly there's something else.  What is it?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

This is from the Chromium Source Project:
https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/panels/network/NetworkWaterfallColumn.ts;l=138-149?q=waterfall%20color&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc

and

https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/panels/timeline/TimelineUIUtils.ts;l=1662-1675?q=TimelineUIUtils&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc

Comment: links dont work

Comment: updated links @droidbee 

Answer (score 2):

In 2020 (at least in Chrome 80) there is no such color-coding

> in the **list** of network requests

in Chrome Network tab. Items, as expected, red colored for error.

The link from [@jaredwilli answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26238591/12610347) is now deprecated and has no info on request types' colors.
Up to date link: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference

But in the settings there is a check box ["Color-code resource types"](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/network-colour-groups). It changes colors of **watefall** bars (not the colors of items in the list of network requests). And these bars become just a little bit reddish for fonts, and for scripts it's pastel orange now.

Also, for the [frames of a WebSocket Connection](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#frames)

> Messages are color-coded according to their type:
>
> - Outgoing text messages are light-green.
> - Incoming text messages are white.
> - WebSocket opcodes are light-yellow.
> - Errors are light-red.

Also, when [hovering other requests with `<Shift>` pressed](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#initiators-dependencies) hovering other requests with `<Shift>` pressed, green is used for initiators of a request and red for dependencies

Answer (score 1):

The colors of the waterfall bars are documented on the Network Performance document of the devtools docs here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#waterfall-view.

- Documents - blue bars
- Stylesheets - green bars
- Images - purple bars
- Scripts - orange bars
- XHR - yellow bars
- Fonts - red bars
- Other - gray bars